# Unhandled Exception when run exe file on remote computer

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error on this code. I'm trying to kill a running process on a remote machine. I'm using `getprocessbyid` and then I kill the process.

```
int pidKill = 2775;
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pidKill);
p.Kill();
```

When I run this script directly on the machine, it works fine, but when I try to run the `.exe` file from remote I got an exception:

```
Unhandled exception: System.ArgumentException: Process with an Id of
2775 is not running at System.Diagnostics.process.GetProcessById(Int
32 ProcessId, string MachineName)
```

Where is the error? Everything works fine when I try to run it directly on server, but when I run it from my workstation I got error.   I'm using this script to run the `.exe` file
I have a button to run the script with this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\SERVERNAME\C$\temp\kill.exe");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that you can't guarantee this to work because you are hard-coding the process id. The process id is not something you can rely on because it is auto-generated by the operating system. That said, `2775` might be the process id on your local machine but it doesn't mean that it will be the same on a remote machine

#### Solution

Use a different method of the `Process` class, instead of using the `GetProcessById` use one of the overloads of `GetProcessesByName` when using `GetProcessesByName`, you can specified the IP address of the remote machine

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessByName("processName", "0.0.0.0"); 
 if(processes != null && processes.Length > 0)
    processes[0].Kill();
```

make sure you specify the correct process name and IP Address

#### Update

I have just realized/remembered that you CANNOT kill a remote process using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API according to the MSDN documentation. It's a bit misleading because they don't explicitly mention that you can't kill a remote process, instead they mention that you can read local and remote processes

> Provides access to local and remote processes and enables you to start and stop local system processes.

but when it comes to remote processes you can only read them, you can't kill them. That leaves you to another option the `Instrumentation` API here's how to achieve a process kill...

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\RemoteMachine\\root\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
QueryObject query = new QueryObject("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name ='ProcessName'");

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

foreach(ManagementObject obj in collection)
{
    obj.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
}
```

This is a reference from [Stanley Gu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/stanleygu/tip-13-kill-a-process-from-local-to-remote)

Comment: The problem is I have another program that is generating a textfile with the processID. and I'm using some code to read the id from the textfile and place it in my  int pidKill

Comment: @djxenon - Doing the approach by Leo avoids you having to create that kind of program to begin with.  I don't see the point of the two programs working in concert.

Comment: kill.exe is running on the server
I call the exe file from my workstation
I have to kill with PID, because I have to processes with same name but different PID

Answer (score 0):

When you run from your workstation you execute the kill program on your local machine and tries to kill process 2775 on your local machine, not on the server.

Comment: kill.exe is running on the server
I call the exe file from my workstation
I have to kill with PID, because I have to processes with same name but different PID